# How to make GoogleCalendarScreenlet to show Google Calendar?

Tags: 16.04, mate, calendar, google-calendar, screenlets

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.6 installed.

I have added `ppa:screenlets/ppa` to it and have installed `screenlets-pack-all` package.

Then I have launched `screenlets` manager and have added GoogleCalendarScreenlet 0.4.16++ to my desktop

[image: no credentials]

have set up the credentials in *Options → gCal essential → Google account*.

It shows notification that login was successful:

> [image]

But it does not show events from my Google Calendar calendar.

Why? Is it just me, or it does not work at all?

Does any working desklet (widget) exist?

---

Some logs are below:

```
$ screenlets

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/screenlets/backend.py:166: Warning: Source ID 2251 was not found when attempting to remove it
  gobject.source_remove(self.__timeout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/screenlets/screenlets-pack-all/GoogleCalendar/GoogleCalendarScreenlet.py", line 133, in __deal_with_data
    all_calendars_feed = self.screenlet.cal_client.GetAllCalendarsFeed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/calendar/service.py", line 81, in GetAllCalendarsFeed
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.calendar.CalendarListFeedFromString)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1107, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
RequestError: {'status': 403, 'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Forbidden</H1>\n<H2>Error 403</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 'reason': 'Forbidden'}

$ tail -f ~/.config/screenlets/GoogleCalendarScreenlet.log
Running update
Checking the Internet connection
Fetching events in calendars from: 2019-05-15T00:00:00+03:00 to 2019-06-05T23:59:59+03:00.
END RETRIEVE
Update failed for some unknown reason.
```

(I see the word *Forbidden* above, so it may be API change issue)

Comment: Go you have `two step/factor authorization` enabled on your Google account? You may need to get an `application-specific password` to get this to work. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Otherwise, go to Google Calendar settings, and note the correct links for public/private iCal access, and others.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks! What is really strange - it works from Evolution with OAuth and without it.

Comment: Let me know how you make out.  And... we have to get you "senior" guys up to using 18.xx or 19.xx... really now :-)

Comment: Any progress on this yet?

Comment: It does not work, but what is interesting it shows [*login successful* notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoXlA.png). Possible I'll switch to [Rainlendar](https://www.rainlendar.net), it is known that it works on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: It's probably a 16.04 problem :-) You might try it out on a Ubuntu Live 19.04 DVD/USB and see if it works... and if it does... that'll be one more reason to upgrade :-)

Comment: @heynnema I got the reason why it is failing. The Ubuntu version is not a problem. Thank you for your kind interest anyway :)

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** - it is impossible because Google disabled ClientLogin and asks applications developers to use OAuth 2.0 instead.

---

Details is below.
The GoogleCalendarScreenlet is based on [`python-gdata` library](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client).
This library has special Google calendar demo program (it is installable from `python-gdata-doc` package). It can be launched with
`/usr/share/doc/python-gdata-doc/examples/calendar/calendarExample.py --user [username] --pw [password]`

When I launch the example program I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/doc/python-gdata-doc/examples/calendar/calendarExample.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/doc/python-gdata-doc/examples/calendar/calendarExample.py", line 613, in main
    sample = CalendarExample(user, pw)
  File "/usr/share/doc/python-gdata-doc/examples/calendar/calendarExample.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.cal_client.ClientLogin(email, password, self.cal_client.source);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 441, in client_login
    captcha_token=captcha_token, captcha_response=captcha_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 373, in request_client_login_token
    response, ClientLoginFailed, response_body)
gdata.client.ClientLoginFailed: Server responded to ClientLogin request: 404, https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps
```

Visiting the https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps page gives one interesting quote:

> **Important:** ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20, 2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

So really it is a "problem" with `python-gdata` library and not GoogleCalendarScreenlet itself.

---

Alternatives:

- for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - [Rainlendar Pro](https://www.rainlendar.net/) (it uses OAuth);
- for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - `indicator-datetime` with GNOME Evolution or GNOME Calendar.